# Picking only black-white and grayscale images for batch-processing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, batch-processing

Is it possible to pick only black-white and grayscale images for photoshop (or another graphical program) batch-processing, even if they are have colored mode (24 or 32 bit). Thus, all pixels bypass is required.

I need in it for conversion of every image to same image with adjust alpha channel. See my another [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/black-white-and-grayscale-to-alpha-conversion-for-images) for detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to that is, no. Photoshop doesn't offer this functionality/criteria in batch mode.

You will need to do it programmatic. Though, be aware that gray-scale images saved in color format may have tint dependent on which color profile was used (if any) so the components may not have the exact same value.

You can overcome this problem by calculating the luminance value from the RGB values and compare it individually with a tolerance range.

Hope that helps.